# Python - surround instances of strings in a given list that are present in another string with HTML

Tags: python, html

I've written a function that surrounds a search term with a HTML element with given attributes. The idea is the resulting surrounded string is written to a log file later on with the search term highlighted.

```
def inject_html(needle, haystack, html_element="span", html_attrs={"class":"matched"}):
    # Find all occurrences of a given string in some text
    # Surround the occurrences with a HTML element and given HTML attributes
    new_str = haystack
    start_index = 0
    while True:
        try:
            # Get the bounds
            start = new_str.lower().index(needle.lower(), start_index)
            end = start + len(needle)

            # Needle is present, compose the HTML to inject
            html_open = "<" + html_element + " " + " ".join(["%s=\"%s\""%(k,html_attrs[k]) for k in html_attrs]) + ">"
            html_close = "</" + html_element + ">"

            new_str = new_str[0:start] + html_open + new_str[start:end] + html_close + new_str[end:len(new_str)]
            start_index = end + len(html_close) + len(html_open)

        except ValueError as ex:
            # String doesn't occur in text after index, break loop
            break
    return new_str
```

I want to open this up to accept an array of needles, locating and surrounding them with HTML in the haystack. I could easily do this by surrounding the code with another loop which iterates through the needles, locating and surrounding instances of the search term. Problem is, this doesn't protect from accidentally surrounding previously injected HTML code., e.g.

```
def inject_html(needles, haystack, html_element="span", html_attrs={"class":"matched"}):
    # Find all occurrences of a given string in some text
    # Surround the occurrences with a HTML element and given HTML attributes
    new_str = haystack
    for needle in needles:
        start_index = 0
        while True:
        try:
            # Get the bounds
            start = new_str.lower().index(needle.lower(), start_index)
            end = start + len(needle)

            # Needle is present, compose the HTML to inject
            html_open = "<" + html_element + " " + " ".join(["%s=\"%s\""%(k,html_attrs[k]) for k in html_attrs]) + ">"
            html_close = "</" + html_element + ">"

            new_str = new_str[0:start] + html_open + new_str[start:end] + html_close + new_str[end:len(new_str)]
            start_index = end + len(html_close) + len(html_open)

        except ValueError as ex:
            # String doesn't occur in text after index, break loop
            break
    return new_str

search_strings = ["foo", "pan", "test"]
haystack = "Foobar"
print(inject_html(search_strings,haystack))

<s<span class="matched">pan</span> class="matched">Foo</span>bar
```

On the second iteration, the code searches for and surrounds the "pan" text from the "span" that was inserted in the previous iteration.

How would you recommend I change my original function to look for a list of needles without the risk of injecting HTML into undesired locations (such as within existing tags).

**--- UPDATE ---**

I got around this by maintaining a list of "immune" ranges (ones which have already been surrounded with HTML and therefore do not need to be checked again.

```
def inject_html(needles, haystack, html_element="span", html_attrs={"class":"matched"}):
    # Find all occurrences of a given string in some text
    # Surround the occurrences with a HTML element and given HTML attributes
    immune = []
    new_str = haystack
    for needle in needles:
        next_index = 0
        while True:
            try:
                # Get the bounds
                start = new_str.lower().index(needle.lower(), next_index)
                end = start + len(needle)

                if not any([(x[0] > start and x[0] < end) or (x[1] > start and x[1] < end) for x in immune]):
                    # Needle is present, compose the HTML to inject
                    html_open = "<" + html_element + " " + " ".join(["%s=\"%s\""%(k,html_attrs[k]) for k in html_attrs]) + ">"
                    html_close = "</" + html_element + ">"

                    new_str = new_str[0:start] + html_open + new_str[start:end] + html_close + new_str[end:len(new_str)]
                    next_index = end + len(html_close) + len(html_open)

                    # Add the highlighted range (and HTML code) to the list of immune ranges
                    immune.append([start, next_index])

            except ValueError as ex:
                # String doesn't occur in text after index, break loop
                break

    return new_str
```

It's not particularly Pythonic though, I'd be interested to see if anyone can come up with something cleaner.

Comment: How do you find `needle`?  This is a good candidate for regular expressions.

Comment: The `needles` are manually entered, they're the strings I wanted to surround with HTML tags.

Comment: Does `needle` need to be an exact match against a given line (case-insensitive)?  Is it a word?  Can `needle` be many lines?

Comment: Yes it has to be an exact match. It's an arbitrary, single-line string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use something like this:

```
def inject_html(phrases, text_body, html_element_name="span", html_attrs={"class":"matched"}):

    new_text_body = []

    html_start_tag = "<" + html_element_name + " ".join(["%s=\"%s\""%(k,html_attrs[k]) for k in html_attrs]) + ">"
    html_end_tag = "</" + html_element_name + ">"

    text_body_lines = text_body.split("\n")

    for line in text_body_lines:
        for p in phrases:
            if line.lower() == p.lower():
                line = html_start_tag + p + html_end_tag
                break

        new_text_body.append(line)

    return "\n".join(new_text_body)
```

It goes through line by line and replaces each line if the line is an exact match (case-insensitive).

**ROUND TWO:**

With the requirement that the match needs to be (1) case-insensitive and (2) matches multiple words/phrases on each line, I would use:

```
import re

def inject_html(phrases, text_body, html_element_name="span", html_attrs={"class": "matched"}):

    html_start_tag = "<" + html_element_name + " " + " ".join(["%s=\"%s\"" % (k, html_attrs[k]) for k in html_attrs]) + ">"
    html_end_tag = "</" + html_element_name + ">"

    for p in phrases:
        text_body = re.sub(r"({})".format(p), r"{}\1{}".format(html_start_tag, html_end_tag), text_body, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

    return text_body
```

For each provided phrase `p`, this uses a case-insensitive `re.sub()` replacement to replace all instances of that phrase in the provided text.  `(p)` matches the phrase via a regular expression group. `\1` is a backfill operator that matches the found phrase, enclosing it in HTML tags.

```
text = """
Somewhat more than forty years ago, Mr Baillie Fraser published a 
lively and instructive volume under the title _A Winter’s Journey  
(Tatar) from Constantinople to Teheran. Political complications 
had arisen between Russia and Turkey - an old story, of which we are 
witnessing a new version at the present time. The English government 
deemed it urgently necessary to send out instructions to our 
representatives at Constantinople and Teheran.
"""

new = inject_html(["TEHERAN", "Constantinople"], text)

print(new)

> Somewhat more than forty years ago, Mr Baillie Fraser published a lively and instructive volume under the title _A Winter’s Journey (Tatar) from <span class="matched">Constantinople</span> to <span class="matched">Teheran</span>. Political complications had arisen between Russia and Turkey - an old story, of which we are witnessing a new version at the present time. The English government deemed it urgently necessary to send out instructions to our representatives at <span class="matched">Constantinople</span> and <span class="matched">Teheran</span>.
```

Comment: Close, but the phrase we're looking for might not be the only content on the line. This will only match if the whole line matches.

Comment: @ryansin Got it - this is the what I meant when when I asked `Does needle need to be an exact match against a given line`.  I should have another POC by tomorrow.

Comment: Ah sorry, yeah my bad I misunderstood.

Comment: Also should consider that there may be more than one instance of a phrase in a given line

Comment: @ryansin I've updated my answer with these requirements.